# Threads running at same time instance

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a requirement threading where I need to initiate a thread which will run continuously doing some DB operations . A second thread will be present which needs to run for every 30 secs. The job of the second thread will be killing the first thread and start a new instance of the first thread.

I tried several ways to achieve this but I am not able to do the same.

```
public class ThreadMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException{

    final CyclicBarrier gate = new CyclicBarrier(3);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                gate.await();
                while(true)
                {
                     System.out.println("Thread1"); 
                     break;

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }};
    Thread t2 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                gate.await();
                while(true)
                {
                     System.out.println("Continiously running thread:-Thread2");     

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }};

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempts?

Comment: Any one of your several ways you tried?

Comment: Hello , I have added the code above . But here it is only running the second thread continuously .O/P I am getting is "Continiously running thread:-Thread2" .I dont know why the first thread output is not getting displayed .

Comment: Ideally it will not print anything since the number of parties is set to 3. Set it to 2 and it should work. Though I am not sure whether that solves your purpose.

Comment: Your design is ... unusual. When you find yourself writing one thread that kills another and then starts a new instance, you should be asking yourself if there's a different way to solve the larger problem that this "solution" is trying to solve.

Comment: Is this a bad joke? Where is your promised *attempt* to solve the problem? I see only two threads containing print statements…

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work nicely:

```
// Thread that runs forever.
volatile static Thread forEverThread = null;

static class ForEver implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("For Ever!");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Just quit if I was interrupted.
        }
    }

}

// Stop the thread if it is running.
private static void stopForeverThread() throws InterruptedException {
    // Skip if non-existent.
    if (forEverThread != null) {
        // Make sure no-one else is already doing it.
        synchronized (forEverThread) {
            // Still not null?
            if (forEverThread != null) {
                // Interrupt it.
                forEverThread.interrupt();
                // Wait for it to finish.
                forEverThread.join();
                // Clear it.
                forEverThread = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void restartForeverThread() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Restarting...");
    // Stop it if it is running.
    stopForeverThread();
    // Start it again.
    forEverThread = new Thread(new ForEver());
    forEverThread.start();
    System.out.println("Restarted");
}

public static void start() throws InterruptedException {
    // Start it all up.
    restartForeverThread();
    // Timed event to restart it.
    Timer restartTimer = new Timer(true);
    restartTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // Restart every few seconds.
                        restartForeverThread();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        // We were interrupted during restart - Log it.
                    }
                }
                // Every few seconds.
            }, 0, 10 * 1000);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        // Start it all up.
        start();
        // Hang around for a while - to see what happens.
        Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database task is interruptible (i.e. it reacts on thread interruption and hence can be cancelled by that), the best strategy is to use an `ScheduledExecutorService` for both, the database task itself and the restart task that runs periodically.

Note that *task* and *thread* are two different things: While a *task* is a piece of work that should be run, *threads* are the mechanism to do this in parallel.

```
static class DatabaseTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}

static class RestartTask implements Runnable {
    private final ExecutorService executor;
    private volatile Future<Void> future;

    public RestartTask(ExecutorService executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (future != null) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
        future = executor.submit(new DatabaseTask());
    }
}

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RestartTask(executor), 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Note that if your `DatabaseTask` is NOT sensitive to thread interruption and continues to perform database operations, the number of threads executing database tasks will grow continously - probably not what you want. So make sure, all blocking database operations are either interruptible, or terminate within a reasonable amount of time.